# Separating real and imaginary parts using Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to segregate real and imaginary parts of the output for the following program.

```
import sympy as sp
a = sp.symbols('a', imaginary=True)
b=sp.symbols('b',real=True)
V=sp.symbols('V',imaginary=True)
a=4*sp.I
b=5
V=a+b
print V
```

Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13):

The lines

```
b=sp.symbols('b',real=True)
V=sp.symbols('V',imaginary=True)
```

have no effect, because you overwrite the variables `b` and `V` in the lines

```
b=5
V=a+b
```

It's important to understand the difference between Python variables and SymPy symbols when using SymPy. Whenever you use `=`, you are assigning a Python variable, which is just a pointer to the number or expression you assign it to. Assigning it again changes the pointer, not the expression. See http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/intro.html and http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

To do what you want, use the `as_real_imag()` method, like

```
In [1]: expr = 4*I + 5

In [2]: expr.as_real_imag()
Out[2]: (5, 4)
```

You can also use the `re()` and `im()` functions:

```
In [3]: re(expr)
Out[3]: 5

In [4]: im(expr)
Out[4]: 4
```